# Persist an entity without attaching it to the EntityManager

Tags: doctrine-orm

I want to bulk-import Doctrine entities from an XML file.

The XML file can be very large (up to 1 million entities), so I can't persist all my entities the traditional way:

```php
$em->beginTransaction();

while ($entity = $xmlReader->readNextEntity()) {
    $em->persist($entity);
}

$em->flush();
$em->commit();
```

I would soon exceed my memory limit, and Doctrine is not really designed to handle that many managed entities.

**I don't need to track changes** to the persisted entities, just to persist them; therefore I don't want them to be managed by the EntityManager.

**Is it possible to persist entities without getting them managed by the EntityManager?**

---

The first option that comes to my mind is to detach it immediately after persisting it:

```php
$em->beginTransaction();

while ($entity = $xmlReader->readNextEntity()) {
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush($entity);
    $em->detach($entity);
}

$em->commit();
```

But this is quite expensive in Doctrine, and would slow down the import.

---

The other option would be to directly insert the data into the database using the `Connection` object and a prepared statement, but I like the abstraction of the entity and would ideally like to store the *object* directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `detach` and `flush` after each insert, you can call `clear` (which detaches all entities from the manager) and `flush` in batches, which should be significantly faster:

> Bulk inserts in Doctrine are best performed in batches, taking
>   advantage of the transactional write-behind behavior of an
>   EntityManager. The following code shows an example for inserting 10000
>   objects with a batch size of 20. You may need to experiment with the
>   batch size to find the size that works best for you. Larger batch
>   sizes mean more prepared statement reuse internally but also mean more
>   work during flush.

https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html

If possible, I recommend avoiding transactions for bulk operations as they tend to slow things down:

```
//$em->beginTransaction();
$i = 0;

while ($entity = $xmlReader->readNextEntity()) {
    $em->persist($entity);
    if(++$i % 20 == 0) {
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear(); // detaches all entities
    }
}

$em->flush(); //Persist objects that did not make up an entire batch
$em->clear();

//$em->commit();
```

Comment: I was hoping to leave the EntityManager in its current state, but it's not a big deal after all. I've also seen that `clear()` accepts an optional class name to only detach entities of a given class, which can be helpful in that case. So I guess this is the only way at the moment!